# trace patterns such that each node is visited only once(eulerian path) using opencv

Tags: opencv, bioinformatics, biopython

Here is my problem which I am trying to solve since one complete year. With no success till end of the year. I have to seek help and a concrete solutions from the stackoverflow experts.

**My problem statement:**

I have been working with some design patterns which I want to trace if eulerian path exist(as shown in below gifs), programmatically. Below are the patterns and the way I wanna draw them(gifs).

**What I wanna achieve:**

Give the design pattern images as input. I want trace the design pattern image in a single stroke as shown in the gifs(gifs animations are just examples of how the patterns is drawn in single stroke). Once I get the x and y coordinates of the image in single stroke fashion(eulerian path). I will feed those coordinates to my program to just trace those coordinates.

**Thing to be noted in the animation:**

1) basically its an undetected graph (the nodes being the vertices of your shapes, the edges if exists being the strokes between 2 vertices). (eulerian path)

**Here are the 15 unique shapes which I used to build the patterns with:**

[image]

I have more then 400 patterns(3 patterns already shown below) and till now I am not able to find a generic solution for this. **I have manually got the x y coordinates of the patterns and placed it in sequence**. But that is not at all scalable.

**How to trace the patterns such that each node is visited only once ?**:

**1st kind of pattern and the way it should be drawn:**

[image]

[image]

**2nd kind of pattern and the way it should be drawn:**

[image]

[image]

**3rd kind of pattern and the way it should be drawn:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Where is the code you have tried? 2. How are we supposed to ever possibly understand the rules that are supposed to drive whatever you're trying to accomplish? This reads like a riddle, not an answerable question.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I have manually plotted the x and y coordinates of the patterns and drawn it. There is no generic solution which I have found. That's why need suggestion on this problem statement.

Comment: But what IS the problem? What exactly are you trying to do? Why does your first example start in the upper left? What are the rules for how to draw? How do you know what shape goes where? Why does this problem need solving? All of those answers are missing from your question.

Comment: I am trying to draw those given patterns in a single stroke. No breakage while drawing. I wanna get the contours(x and y coordinates) and rearrange them such that I can draw those patterns in single stroke. @DarkFalcon

Comment: You can devide your patterns into groups based on the number of vertices (i.e 1 for tear drop shape, 4 for square etc). Total number of patterns in an image is directly proportional to the number of dots, what remains is how to choose patterns. The grouping can help that. For example, if you choose a square, then you know that it has 4 vertices, so 4 more patterns are required because none of the vertices can be left open. This way you can select more.

Comment: I partially understood your idea @zindarod . Please provide a little broad explanation. I will implement that.

Comment: to be more general. Give the above design pattern images as input. I want trace the design pattern image in a single stroke as shown in the gifs(gifs animations are just examples of how the patterns is drawn in single stroke).

Comment: You basically already have an undetected graph (the nodes being the vertices of your shapes, the edges if exists being the strokes between 2 vertices). Check if exists an [eulerian path](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) and you're done

Comment: a broader explanation will be of great help @Miki

Comment: @Miki From what I understand, his problem can be defined: 1-number of dots/patterns. 2-Selection and placement of patterns such that there are no open vertices. In your comment, I think you assume that he already has the shapes.

Comment: [I'm not assuming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115316/5008845) ;) @zind

Comment: @zindarod Miki already solved the assumption part which you talking about   :)

Comment: How will I convert this pattern images into undirectional graph ? Please forgive If I am not sounding right. @Miki

Comment: @Miki I am confused. In the link he says, "*I have 15 unique shapes...using which I can draw different patterns*", then he says, "*I have more than 400 patterns...find out different shapes*". Which is it? Does he want to draw patterns or process already drawn pattern for eulerian path?

Comment: I have 15 unique shapes which I used to make a complete pattern. I have already mentioned those 15 shapes here in the question as well. @zindarod

Comment: @zind that's a good question

Comment: You could have just asked: How to trace the patterns such that each node is visited only once?

Comment: I am extremely sorry @zindarod :( my bad

Comment: I have designed 400 design patterns using those 15 unique shapes @zindarod

Comment: @Miki no problem. I may have confused you guys coz even I am struggling for a year to solve this. Hope by now the problem statement is clear ? :) I really appreciate your patience for bearing with me.

Comment: Then @Miki's comment about eulerian path stands. Select an arbitrary point, check if an eulerian path exists, if yes then terminate, if not then select another point and repeat.

Comment: @zindarod you have any confusion or doubt ? I am ready to give you any detailed explanation you want.

Comment: @Miki I have gone through the link you provided and its perfect for this problem. how can I traverse the above patterns as graphs ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can look into the traveling salesman problem if your still struggling with the above. TSP visits cities only once. And if in your case each node is a crossing for your strike-through then this might help.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552656/python-traveling-salesman-greedy-algorithm) for the python code to look at. I've checked and the print statement looks nice and structured. Well done cMinor!

Edit based on discussion: [file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chhli.jpg), [file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHZp7.jpg), [file3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngnbX.jpg).

Comment: TSP is used for visiting all the cities in such a way that the travel distance is minimal. But I am trying to find the eulerian path in the pattern. That will help me to trace the pattern in single stroke without lifting the pointer or cursor.

Comment: My bad. In this case I ment "node" to be an intersection/connection between two (out of your 400) tiles. Can you count the amount of squares during the manufacturing of your image? If so then in your canvas 3x3 and 4x4 tiles there should only be one square drawn. If your canvas is 5x5 or more there should be a space distance between two squares of at least one tile. Otherwise you get overlap. Include that in your code to avoid and your safe. Then any x,y point can be used to start with the single stroke draw. Apply this rule too if used to pentagons and hexagons; and between them off-course.

Comment: check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115316/5008845 
This gives me all the squares through the image. Thanks to @Miki

Comment: The image I've added shows a blue square and red-crossed square to help visually what I mean by previous comment. That solution looks nice... not python though ;-)

Comment: 400 are designs..there are only 15 tiles...and my problem is..how to get the x and y co-ordinate of the nodes and the path :(  @ZF007

Comment: If you look at tile 1 of [unique tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRzsX.png) do the curvations of the drop-like shape touch the sides of an imaginary square? If so make a new figure where the curvation does not touch the sides; only the pointy point that will be interconnected with the blackline in an another tile. If you do this for all you can overlay it and search with defined parameters for square size. This way you get the outlines of the square (a.k.a. first pixel row). On three sides of the square bgr(0,0,0) and on side 4 you get somewhere a bunch of (bgr(255, 255, 255) pixels.

Comment: calculate the centre of it and you got a node coordinate for that particar tile in the figure. Do that for all others as well and you get there quite easily. Compare x,y with that of the next tile data(s) and in some cases you find coords x1 = x2 or y1 = y2 are similar. And voila you got your junctions/internodes.

Comment: Let me try it out. I do need to read your comments twice to fully digest it. :) It is a great idea. Let me try implementing that.

Comment: If you can add some images with your explanation. It will help me to get your idea clearly @ZF007

Comment: Added two examples (file 2 and 3) of outline data reduction.In the first there is the raindrop -like figure as is and reduced contact at outline. Second figure shows the square with total outline contact and with only four corner contacts.